# After restart Elementary OS stuck on boot logo

Tags: boot

I can access some kind of terminal when I press buttons.

Can anyone help me how to reset or reinstall using commands.

Or

Better, can you tell me how to boot USB from command line? Because my bios boot options not works :/

I am kinda stuck.

Here is Reddit video:

https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/cjaghe/elementary_os_cant_boot/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share

Comment: Please specify, what do you mean by saying that your BIOS boot options do not work. You can't select your USB stick as a boot device in BIOS?

Comment: I'd recommend to reset the bios and try booting a bootable usb. You may need to open your laptop and unplug the battery (the bios battery and the normal battery).